# Multi-statelevel detection

Tags: matlab, algorithms

I'm trying to develop an automated state-detection algorithm, basically expanding on MatLab's ["statelevels"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/statelevels.html?s_tid=doc_ta) function to multiple (i.e. 3+) states, however I've hit a brick wall in trying to figure out how to define histogram bin edges without prior knowledge of the signal and have not been able to find any literature which isn't locked behind a paywall. Does anyone have suggestions, either for an algorithm to achieve multi-state detection or for publicly-available literature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for cluster detection. In your case, it's very basic: there's no more than one dimension along which to detect clusters.

It's probably overkill, but 1-dimensional k-means is probably what you want.

Matlab has good documentation on k-means. (Also, seriously, all this is wikipedia or textbook knowledge, there's very many free resources. You very rarely start reading research papers when you enter a new field.)

Comment: This is definitely the line of inquiry I need to follow. As green to all this as I am, I don't necessarily know the proper terminology to find what I'm actually looking for. Thanks!